# Apply CSS if date older than today in php file

Tags: php

I have a table in php fed by mysql that displays upcoming events. Would it be possible to apply css to a table cell or row if the date is older than today or maybe if date is today? I would like to maybe colour the row red id date is older than today?

A typical example of my table row which displays the dates is  `<td><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $row_rsEventChase['start_date']; ?>"></abbr></td>`

Any help much appreciated..

Comment: There's no way to do it with pure `css`. You'll need to check date and  depending on it add some CSS class in js or php.

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
<td><abbr class="<?php echo ($row_rsEventChase['start_date'] <= (time() - 86400)) ? "old" : "new"; ?>" title="<?php echo $row_rsEventChase['start_date']; ?>"></abbr></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$isOlderThanDay = (time() - $row_rsEventChase['start_date'] > 86400) ? true : false;
if ($isOlderThanDay) {
   $css = "color: red;";
} else {
   $css = "";
}

<td><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $row_rsEventChase['start_date']; ?>" style="<?php echo $css; ?>"></abbr></td>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I did try this placing the code at top of page in php tags but whatever the date, future or past it leaves the field white. When I look at the page source it shows  
    <td>2012-04-09 15:00:00</td>

    <td><abbr class="timeago" title="2012-04-09 15:00:00"   style="color: red;"></abbr></td>

      <td>2012-04-22 10:28:00</td>

      <td><abbr class="timeago" title="2012-04-22 10:28:00" style="color: red;"></abbr></td>

Sorry cant format this! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe you have something wrong in your CSS class timeago. i don't know tag <abbr> but try to testi it with <span> and remove the timeago class. just for test. hope you find out what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Castor, I ran this on a test page with no css class, just <td> exactly as your suggestion, cant work out why it always chooses red even though some dates are in the future..

Comment: do a print_r or var_dump on time(), $row_rsEventChase['start_date'] and (time() - $row_rsEventChase['start_date']) on every record. This should lead to problem diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do the check out of the cell in order to apply style to the whole row. For instance:

```
<style>
tr.new td {
background: #FFC;
}
tr.old td {
background: #eee;
}
<style>
<tr class="<?php echo ($row_rsEventChase['start_date'] <= (time() - 86400)) ? "old" : "new"; ?>"> 
    <td>....</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, I also tried this but it coloured every row red, when I swapped the 'old' : 'new' around in the code it then changed all colours, seesm its taking everything as the 1st option rather than checking date to see if its 24 hours old?

Thanks again..